# How Sentry auto send log except to mail?

Tags: python, django, sentry

I use Sentry to log exceptions for my project and all is OK.

But I don't know how to make Sentry auto-send notifications to my email (example as gmail,v.v) when there is an exception.

Help me.

```
# This is config setting:
# For more information check Django's documentation:
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/email/?from=olddocs#e-mail-backends

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False

# The email address to send on behalf of
SERVER_EMAIL = 'my_mail@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your sentry settings

Go to http:///account/settings/notifications/

[image: settings]

P.S. Django usually email to addresses in "ADMIN" setting

Comment: Hey, bro, what do you recommend for sending emails about errors - from sentry, or directly from django and celery?

Comment: I prefer sentry slack integration or smth